# Changing Password Automation / Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am working on automation in Java. I am getting data from "test.properties" file. I would like to change password on a website from user settings panel. There are some elements;

- First input: Old password
- Second input: New password
- Third input: New password repeat
- Submit: Save

How can I create proper automation for this one?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly these are the steps you should follow:

1. Create a Test class.
2. Initialise your web driver (Chrome or Firefox) before entering in the test case (@Before)
3. `driver.get(https://<your_website>)`
4. Find your inputs and submit button:

   ```
   @FindBy(id = "<your_form>:<password>")
   private WebElement textPassword;`

   @FindBy(id = "<your_form>:<submitButton>")
   private WebElement submitButton;`
   ```
5. Send keys to the web elements:

   ```
   textPassword.sendKeys(<your_password>)
   ```
6. click on submit

   ```
   submitButton.click();
   ```

You can find a good tutorial at [softwaretesting.com](http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2014/05/submitting-form-using-submit-method-of.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to change the password using script,

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ChangePassword
{
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","specify your chromedriver.exe path here");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            String URL = "Your site url";
            driver.get(URL);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            //Old Password
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("Old Password Field xpath here")).sendKeys("old password");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("New Password Field xpath here")).sendKeys("new password");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("Re-enter Password Field xpath here")).sendKeys("new password");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("Submit button xpath")).click();
   }     
}
```